# Convert java.lang.String to int in android

Tags: android, string, tags, integer

How to convert java.lang.String to int in Android? 
I wrote this code but it does not work:

```
public static String code;
...
db.insertQuote(Integer.parseInt(code));
```

I use this code and when I read NFC Tags I want that this function will be run, but it gives me an error and because I use a real mobile for test, I cannot understand what is happening.

Comment: Why does it fails? What is the error? "because i use real mobile for test,i can not understand what is happened" oO How so?

Comment: Logcat still exists for "real mobile" ...

Comment: it gives me force close in mobile
but when i use code="09877776" manually,it works!

Comment: Is your string null? where did you give it a value? Show the related code.

Comment: Beware of converting your String to an int, you will loose the padding 0...

Comment: variables in java start with a lowercase char, this applie to the Code variable name as well ;)

Comment: I read Tag with Mobile and put codes of goods in this function,i chek it but string is not null

Comment: Then your tag reading might return null!. Try logging the value.

Comment: Read up on basic Java. It makes Android development a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most easiest answer is :

```
       int i = Integer.parseInt(StringValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    int i=Integer.parseInt(stringvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

so, assuming the code have other value than a number, you should debug, and test the value of `code`, if it would blank it will also throw, `NumberFormatException`, or if its NullPointerException, then String code might not be initialized yet.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're initializing `Code` properly before calling `Integer.parseInt(Code)`?
If `Code` is still only defined, but not initialized (no assignement is ever made to `Code`), then that is your problem.
Apart from this you have to make sure that `Code` really is a number, so I suggest the following:

```
public static String Code;
... //rest of your code here
if(Code != null)
{
  try
  {
    db.insertQuote(Integer.parseInt(Code));
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException e)
  {
    //execution will get here if Code is not a number
    //insert code to handle this chase
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String number;
int x = Integer.valueOf(number);
```